# Google Places Library geolocation not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got problem with geolocation. If i open my html file(javascript Google Places) browser ask me for permission and if i agree maps and geolocation works fine. But in android i can't agree becouse windows doesnt' show like in browser. I have tried pass Lat and Long to file and open but still nothing i have got error: "The Geolocation service failed.".

This is working fine if i agree(html)

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
   var pos = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
};
```

But this is not working(when i have tried open variable from file, for example I have pasted numbers instead my file with lat and lng. Effect is that same, not working)

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    var pos = {
        lat: 52.229676,
        lng: 21.012229
    };
```

On android i have that same error.

I have tried this for save variable and open in javascript but error still: "The Geolocation service failed.(C# class)

```
private void PrintPosition(Position position)
{
 // string path = @"C:\Users\Anon\Source\Repos\Ap\Ap\Ap\Wspol.txt";
 var Late = position.Latitude;
 var Longe = position.Longitude;

 var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
 Java.IO.File sdCard = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
 Java.IO.File dir = new Java.IO.File(sdCard.AbsolutePath + "/MyFolder");
 dir.Mkdirs();
 Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(dir, "Lat.txt");
 Java.IO.File filee = new Java.IO.File(dir, "Long.txt");

 if (!file.Exists() || file.Exists())
 {
    file.CreateNewFile();
    file.Mkdir();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    // Writes the content to the file
    writer.Write("" + Late);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
 }

    if (!filee.Exists() || filee.Exists())
    {
      filee.CreateNewFile();
      filee.Mkdir();
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filee);
      // Writes the content to the file
      writer.Write("" + Longe);
      writer.Flush();
      writer.Close();
      }
}
```

How can i get permission in Javascript or get geolocation without permission thaht i could open the map on my place.

Comment: How did you open the map in Android ?

Comment: i used webview.

Comment: You could refer to : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/

Comment: but my maps is working good and i have markers etc. I only need to ask user for access or get access other way

Comment: Is this only happened on Android 6.0 + device?

Comment: on Android 5.1.1 too

Comment: On android 7.0 that same effect